# Security Token Validation Error with JWT token -- HDInsight

Tags: powershell, azure, hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I created a new storage account and provisioned an HDInsight cluster on Windows Azure. However, when I try to run any command on Windows Azure Powershell related to the cluster, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureHDInsightCluster -Name $clusterName
Get-AzureHDInsightCluster : Request failed with code:Unauthorized
Content:<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>A security token
validation error occured for the received JWT token.</Message></Error>
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureHDInsightCluster -Name $clusterName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureHDInsightCluster], HttpLayerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Hadoop.Client.HttpLayerException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.C
   mdlet.PSCmdlets.GetAzureHDInsightClusterCmdlet
```

I'm completely new to HDInsight, but I ran a script before this command to add the Azure account, create variables for the subscription name, storage account name, and container name from [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-get-started/) page.

Do you know what this error means? And how to fix it? I'm trying to run a script with Pig commands after following [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-pig/#nextsteps) website.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the PowerShell environment is not properly setup. You should add your Azure subscription first with GetAzureSubscription. See: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/#Connect

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Simon. I used "Add-AzureAccount" and it seemed to connect to my subscription, and I was able to verify the name with "Get-AzureSubscription." Any ideas what else I may be missing?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but if this answer did not help you solve the problem -although the tip might be really helpful-, you should not mark it as the final solution, since it could considerably reduce the chances of getting more answers from other contributors. Instead, an upvote might be a better way to go.